# Check if tabBar is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tabbar

I'm trying to see if my TabBar is nil.

In Objective-C I would do so:

```
if(self.tabBar != nil){
}
```

if I try to do this to me in swift returns this error:

***'UITabBar' is not a subtype of 'NSString'***

This is the code that I have to write in whole swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //check tabBar not null
    if (self.tabBar != nil)
    {
        //make changes in frame here according to orientation if any
        self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 00, y: 20, width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 49)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Try `if(self.tabBar){
}`

Comment: get me error: 'UITabBar'  does not conform protocoll boolean type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
let tabBar: UITabBar?
tabBar =  //initialize tabBar
if tabBar != nil {

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The viewController's `tabBarController` is an optional. The `tabBar` inside a `UITabBarController` is not an optional. Thus you might try:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
            // use your tabBarController
            tabBarController.tabBar // the tabBar in the tabBarController is not an optional
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are overriding a standard `ViewController` if you are overriding a `UITabBarController` then your `tabBar` is not an optional, so you don't need the nil check.